# What is the replacement for DriveResourceClient?

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am new to Google API.  By following the official Google API sample (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client?authuser=0), I tried to create a DriveResourceClient object to connect my app with  Google Drive.  Unfortunately, I found that DriveResourceClient is deprecated. I wonder if the official guide I am reading is the latest version or not. If not, is there any latest Google API guide I can rely on? The guide I am currently reading was last updated on March 13, 2019.

Thanks.

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

// Get the app's Drive folder
DriveResourceClient client = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(this,account);
client.getAppFolder().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<DriveFolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DriveFolder>() {
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/) 
This is the Drive REST API.

Comment: Hi, may you advise me any reference for calling Drive Rest API with Android please?

Comment: @BrianLo Which kind of drive resource you want to access?

Answer (score 0):

Download by link: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples.git

Open project "deprecation". This example will help access account and download files by SAF. If you received your application credentials in the developer console: https://console.cloud.google.com

Comment: Wait, the newest one is "deprecation" ? This is what we should use?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: You said "Open project "deprecation"." . This is the newest version that we should all look at? I thought that "deprecation" means we shouldn't..

Comment: I see. No. Its (project) name is "deprecation".

Comment: Yes, you should look at it :)